# vertx mongo authentification

Tags: java, mongodb, vert.x

i get an error while authenticating. the documentation in vertx is so minimalized

```
MongoAuthenticationOptions options = new MongoAuthenticationOptions()
                                       .setCollectionName("users");
JsonObject credentials =new JsonObject().put("username","admin").put("password","admin");
MongoAuthentication authenticationProvider=MongoAuthentication.create(client, options);
authenticationProvider.authenticate(credentials)
  .onSuccess(user -> System.out.println("User: " + user.principal()))
  .onFailure(err -> {
    System.out.println("Error");
  });
```

the error

```
avr. 28, 2022 3:22:21 AM io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void io.vertx.ext.auth.impl.UserImpl.<init>(io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject)'
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.mongo.impl.MongoAuthenticationImpl.createUser(MongoAuthenticationImpl.java:170)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.mongo.impl.MongoAuthenticationImpl.handleSelection(MongoAuthenticationImpl.java:150)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.mongo.impl.MongoAuthenticationImpl.lambda$authenticate$0(MongoAuthenticationImpl.java:107)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to do normal authentification, this is like the code in documentation but it give me error

Comment: This error indicates there's a mismatch between the Vert.x component versions.

Comment: how can i solve that ??